# Looping over rows in Pandas dataframe taking too long

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have been running the code for like 45 mins now and is still going. Can someone please suggest to me how I can make it faster?

df4 is a panda data frame. df4.head() looks like this

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame({ 
    'hashtag':np.random.randn(3000000),
    'sentiment_score':np.random.choice( [0,1], 3000000),
    'user_id':np.random.choice( ['11','12','13'], 3000000),
    })
```

What I am aiming to have is a new column called rating.

len(df4.index) is 3,037,321.

```
ratings = []
for index in df4.index:
    rowUserID = df4['user_id'][index]
    rowTrackID = df4['track_id'][index]
    rowSentimentScore = df4['sentiment_score'][index]

    condition = ((df4['user_id'] == rowUserID) & (df4['sentiment_score'] == rowSentimentScore))
    allRows = df4[condition]
    totalSongListendForContext = len(allRows.index)

    rows = df4[(condition & (df4['track_id'] == rowTrackID))]
    songListendForContext = len(rows.index)

    rating = songListendForContext/totalSongListendForContext
    ratings.append(rating)
```

Comment: Looping is not good in this case. And you should give a small sample data and expected output from that sample. That way people are more likely to help you.

Comment: Okay, I did what you suggested me to do

Comment: No, not like that. Something as suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: what is `condition`?

Comment: Hi @Ben.T ,  condition is ((df4['user_id'] == rowUserID) & (df4['sentiment_score'] == rowSentimentScore))

Answer (score 1):

Globally, you'll need `groupby`. you can either:

use two `groupby` with [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#transformation) to get the `size` of what you called `condition` and the `size` of the `condition & (df4['track_id'] == rowTrackID)`, divide the second by the first:

```
df4['ratings'] = (df4.groupby(['user_id', 'sentiment_score','track_id'])['track_id'].transform('size')
                   / df4.groupby(['user_id', 'sentiment_score'])['track_id'].transform('size'))
```

Or use `groupby` with [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) with the parameter `normalize=True` and `merge` the result with df4:

```
df4 = df4.merge(df4.groupby(['user_id', 'sentiment_score'])['track_id']
                   .value_counts(normalize=True)
                   .rename('ratings').reset_index(),
                how='left')
```

in both case, you will get the same result as your list `ratings` (that I assume you wanted to be a column). I would say the second option is faster but it depends on the number of groups you have in your real case.